# WordPress Update caused Problems

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have updated my WordPress site to the latest version and caused many errors in my site. I have my debugger set to true in my wp-config

I believe updating WordPress won't delete database that we have right?

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function getMultipleRecords2() in /home/xtmpi.ac.cy/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/xenia/header.php on line 6**

Since this one is made by a programmer a couple of years ago, i have no idea with his PHP codes...

Here's the code of header.php from line 4 to 23

```
<?php 
$qry="SELECT * FROM xtmpi order by recordListingID ASC;";
$xtmpi_blog=getMultipleRecords2($qry);

$qry="SELECT * FROM students order by recordListingID ASC;";
$student_m=getMultipleRecords2($qry);
$qry="SELECT * FROM parents order by recordListingID ASC;";
$parent_m=getMultipleRecords2($qry);
$qry="SELECT * FROM course order by recordListingID ASC;";
$acd_progs=getMultipleRecords2($qry);
$qry="SELECT * FROM eduservice order by recordListingID ASC;";
$edu_serv=getMultipleRecords2($qry);
$qry="SELECT * FROM skywalkers order by recordListingID ASC;";
$sky_list=getMultipleRecords2($qry);
$qry="SELECT * FROM general order by recordListingID ASC;";
$gen_list=getMultipleRecords2($qry);

session_start();

?>
```

Comment: Try to re-uploading your whole wordpress folder except for the wp-content folder. this should fix your problem.

Comment: I'll try this..  but i just updated my wordpress files via Dashboard. Isn't that the same?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your developer had updated some wordpress core file at some point and your upgrade has wiped out this change.

The theme you are using depends on a function called `getMultipleRecords2()` which is now missing.

If the only thing you have done is update wordpress then unfortunately you may have to restore from a backup to fix this issue.

If you check your backup code for a line that starts like this

```
function getMultipleRecords2(
```

and put that code block into /home/xtmpi.ac.cy/public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/functions.php then that **MAY** solve your problem, but I guess there will be further issues after that.

Comment: I didn't do any backup when i updated the wordpress core files... :(

Comment: If you have no backups of the site how it was before the upgrade, then you are probably going to have to get used to the idea of picking a new theme for your site. This is why it reminds you to back up your files and database when you do the upgrade

Comment: bad.. always update your files. Lately there was a post on SO where a user deleted his index.php.. same problem. ALWAYS BACKUP YOUR FILES.

Comment: Found the BACKUP!! i never thought i had one... ill check the function getMultipleRecords2(  code in my backup